# How to program for Windows in Ubuntu? 20.04

Tags: c++

Is there anyway to create C++ windows console applications inside Ubuntu's IDE and compile it for Windows?

I have a C++ program that includes windows.h . This program works fine on windows but on my ubuntu 20.04 when I compile the code with:

```
gcc main.cpp
```

I get:

```
HFmanager billing system.cpp:2:9: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory 
    2 | #include<windows.h>
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can i get the windows.h and what shall I do to be able to use Windows API ??

Comment: You need a special version of GCC targeting Windows, called "mingw".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat does it come with Windows headers and libraries?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, a sane distribution should.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat He wants to program for windows on Linux, not the other way around. This is done with package called `wine` and `winegcc` compiler in particular.

Comment: @oakad In my book, "for windows" means producing binaries that run on Windows. But a clarification from OP would be nice.

Comment: He rather clearly writes that he is trying to compile and run a program on Linux which happens to include "windows.h". A very clear cut case for wine. :-)

Comment: OP, what OS do you want the resulting program to run on?

Comment: Well as you need to test the resulting executable on Wndows anyway, why not develop in Windows?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i installed the "mingw" with this cmd 'sudo apt-get install g++-mingw-w64' but i still have the same problem

Comment: The compiler is called differently, not `gcc`. I believe it's `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`.